# Open multiple internet shortcut files at once?

Tags: windows, shortcuts

Is there an easy way to open multiple internet shortcuts (.url files) at once?

Whenever I try to open multiple links at once only the last one selected is opened.

I've tried hitting enter, right-click open, and dragging into the web browser.

Comment: You could just have them open by default when you open your browser? (but that would means you will open all of them whether you wanted it or not)

Comment: I just discovered that dragging and dropping _does_ work on Firefox. Chrome still only opens one page though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified Adelaide's answer to open selected files. I've put it on the desktop so that I can drag and drop onto it.

```
for %%x in (%*) do %%x
```

Comment: good addition, looks like that will work nicely

Answer (score 0):

A batch file with the following command will open all URL files in the same folder location at once in your default browser:

```
for %%X in (*.url) do %%X
```

Comment: Interesting. But opening everything would be too much. I'd rather open 10 tabs at a time instead of 100+. Maybe change it to drag and drop onto a batch file... I'll have to look into it later.

Comment: For shortcuts with spaces in the name, quotation marks are required when the name is used as a command; i.e. `do "%%x"`